# how can I change chips color in Primeng?

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, chips

I want to change color chips in primeng,that whenever I select one I get a diffrent color!, can anyone help me how to do that!

[image]

my code :

```
 <p-multiSelect [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCars1"  [selectionLimit]=3 [panelStyle]="{minWidth:'12em'}"
                         [maxSelectedLabels]=2></p-multiSelect>
          <p>Selected Cars: </p>
          <p-chips [(ngModel)]="selectedCars1" ></p-chips>
```

Comment: Show us some code and workout!

Answer (score 2):

To add a different background to your PrimeNG chips, you can do the following,

- In your component.html file,

```html
<p-chips [(ngModel)]="selectedCars" (onAdd)="onChipAdd($event)"></p-chips>
```

- In your component.ts file,

Create an event handler for the `onAdd` event along with a function to select all elements in the document with the CSS selector `li.p-chips-token`. This function essentially helps in accessing all the PrimeNG chips.

Since the requirement specifies that the background of each PrimeNG chip should differ, we would need to also create a function to generates random colors.

```js
onChipAdd(event) {
  console.log(event);
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.modifyBackground(), 0
  });

}

generateBackground() {
  let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

modifyBackground() {
  let colorOfInterest = this.generateBackground();
  let chipsOfInterest =
    document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('li.p-chips-token');
  console.log(chipsOfInterest);
  if (chipsOfInterest.length > 0) {
    let chipOfInterest = chipsOfInterest[chipsOfInterest.length - 1];
    chipOfInterest.style.backgroundColor = colorOfInterest;
  }
}
```

**TLDR;**

For your reference, please find link to a working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-chips-demo-zbpe1e?file=src/app/app.component.html)

***Edit:***

If your requirement was to only change the background color of the PrimeNG chip from the default background color, please do the following.

In your styles.css file,

```css
.p-chips ul.p-chips-multiple-container .p-chips-token {
  color: #000; 
  background: #dfdfdf !important; /* Add the required background color */
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work for me :/

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: still the blue color doesnt change

Comment: Please refer to the following [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-chips-demo-zbpe1e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I don't know why it dosnt work either ! I am using angular 8 + primeng 8

Answer (score -2):

Maybe I'm a bit late but I achieve it in the following way and add a Border-Radius

```
<p-chip [ngStyle]="{'background': '#EF5350','border-radius': '15px' }"></p-chip>
```